# vb.net determine if richtextbox is empty

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox (RTB) that I am using to save text to a SQLite DB
To prevent the user from not entering text in the RTB I have implemented the code below
The issue is after the user enters some text in the RTB clicking the SAVE button will not bypass the test
**Question is there a better way to do this and why is this code failing?**

```
    If Len(Trim(rtbEnter.Text = " ")) Then
        tbMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red
        tbMessage.Text = "No Data to Enter"
        Return
    End If
```

Comment: `If rtbEnter.Text.Trim() = "" Then`

Comment: You mean `If rtbEnter.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then ...`

Comment: @Jimi Where I work they advocate this form, and I always had doubts. Is there a significant difference?

Comment: Do one thing, apparently simple: set `Option Strict On` for a moment, see what happens. The difference is more than *significant*, you're trimming and testing the length of a boolean.

Comment: Is this .NET or vb6?

Comment: This is VB.Net TAG and Question make that statement YES I do some VB 6 now and then @Jimi Need a little more path to Option Strict On I did test the code and it solves the issue laancelot do you have another form?

Comment: So why do you code like vb6? Use the .NET way as shown above and your code will be OK. :)

Comment: I think both code snippets works, but @Jimi here have **much** more experience than I, so I may be missing some key factor here.

Comment: @Jimi Turned Option Strict ON and your code works but my code does not work

Comment: @Vector Your code snippet has several problems. First, as Jimi stated, you're testing the length of a boolean. Then, you're trimming a string (so the spaces disappears) and testing it _against a space_. It'll always be different. The whole thing is off.

Comment: The reason why the code you posted doesn't work is already explained: `rtbEnter.Text = " "` returns `True` or `False` (a bool), then you try to trim it and test the length of the result. Won't go well :) What I posted and what @laancelot posted, in this context, are ~equivalent (one tests the content, one the length of the content): pick whatever you're more comfortable with.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the explanation about the boolean I actually tried to get the length of the RTB.Text and had no luck but did not use Trim I need to read WHY it is a boolean that part is confusing

Comment: You need to fix all the `Option Strict On disallows implicit conversion from x to y ...` errors in you code. That's what I meant above, use the .NET way to produce the right code.

Comment: _I am lost as what you are asking I do not use VB 6 code in the VS IDE I started coding with VB 6 when you may have been filling your diapers_ Thank you.

Comment: The WHY... `If Len(Trim(RichTextBox1.Text = " ")) Then` As you know evaluation starts with the inner parenthesis. This is an If statement. The If is evealuating `RichTextBox1.Text = " "` as True of False. True and False are Boolean values and cannot be trimmed and do not have a lenght concept like a string. You could write `If Len(Trim(rtbEnter.Text)) > 0 Then`

Comment: @Mary This is what happens when a NOVICE is hanging on to JavaFX and VB 6 It took me a while to realize "ZERO" and "False" are the same so I have seen my way out of the  darkness with this If Len(tbTitle.Text.Trim) = CInt(False) Then and If Len(tbTitle.Text.Trim) = 0 Then Ted still wants to play Bridge ha ha

Comment: Just logged off from almost 8 hours of online bridge with friends. Keep Option Strict On to avoid these oddities.